# Create dynamic classic report for uploading files, with file type in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, file-upload, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-22

In **oracle apex**, i have a table that have the columns: file_type, file_name, and the content of type blob, and the id (primary key). And i have in another table, the name of the files to be uploaded (curriculum vitae, cover letter...). I want in oracle apex, a classic report that has 2 columns: the name of the file to be uploaded (from the second table) and an upload button that if the user clicks upload directly it will redirect the user to the PC documents. And after the user uploads the file, it will be saved in the first table. I created another table only to have things **dynamically** and if i want to add for example "school grades" in the second table, it will be added directly in the classic report because it pull the information from the table.

I tried to do it but i don't want another page to upload files, and if i want to add file type in the table to be added directly in the classic report

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to have an inline file upload. This is not supported in an interactive grid (that is the only editable report region and it doesn't have a "file upload" column type).
I'm pretty sure you don't need a separate page. This is how I would do it - I have not tested it, it's just a high level overview.

1. Create the classic report with the "Upload" button
2. Create a dynamic action on click of the "Upload" button, setting the primary key value of that row in a page item.
3. Create a file upload region (should only have the "file browse..." page item) with a submit button. This region will handle the file upload. Region should be hidden by default (with dynamic action)
4. Add a true action to the dynamic action on the upload button to show the upload region when clicked.

This way the upload is still done with a page submit

Comment: This is one of the ways it can be resolved, thank you!